# multi tenant or multi instance application on intranet

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing MVC app which will be utlized by another user group in the near future. Both the existing and new user group/program will have independant data. I was just thinking to add flags in the tables to distinguish between the two user group/programs and do some routing when they access the application to pull up respective data.

Now when it comes to code customization, for instance one group/program wants to have extra fields on a page which the first group does not want or the process flow of the application is seperate between the two user groups.

If the above two scenarios will occur frequently, should I just do a new web and database instance rather than customizing the code for each program/user group. This way both of my customers/user groups will have flexibility to add different logic/fields to the application.

The only con I see with the non-multi tenant approach is the time effort by the developer to maintain two seperate applications. I am scared of adding contional logic to customize the same code base for each different user group/program. Cost of infrastructure is not an issue. Also I do not forsee this application to be used by more than 2 user groups/programs at any time.  So what do you guys think which apporach i should take and why?  thanks all in advance

P.S The users arent any ninjas who will try to hack the site to see the other tenants data. They are corporate users.  Theyd rather not use this application but its part of the process so they have to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth taking a look at microsoft's [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) on multi-tenancy.

I'm also working on trying to design an mvc app with such an architecture where each client can have separate fields and customised screens.

The conclusion that I have come to is that using an IOC container with multi-tenancy support will probably make the whole thing a lot easier.

Autofac has built in [multi-tenancy support](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration).

In terms of having logic for clients in each view I believe that if you go down the IOC path you can have a controller for each tenant and in that case hard coding such client specific logic isn't necessarily as bad as it would be having it hard coded all into a shared controller. In essence I believe when writing a component that is for a particular tenant you can switch you mindset to writing as if that tenant was the only one using the system.

The other solution I have landed in for customising views is to use a variation of the [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com) approach for compiled views where I have each tenants views compiled into a separate assembly and have created my own view engine (based on [this](http://razorcontrib.codeplex.com/)) where I can swap out the assembly that I look for views in depending on a value in the routing parameters.

Of course I'm still exploring this approach and haven't fully flushed it out in order to find out where it may fall short.

Comment: Your IOC container sounds wise. My current user base is close to 150 users and potenially adding another 100 users in the new user group. With this apporach even if I have another 2 or 3 three new programs/users groups and depending on their need, I could still have everything under one source project. With different controllers I could even use seperate tables if need be. I will investigate further to see how easy the implementaion would be. thanks buddy!

Answer (score 2):

If the difference in the 2 users' requirements is more than 10% of the screens/functionality then you better have 2 databases and apps. If it is expected to be less than 10% then just write separate actions (possibly with different prefixes or suffixes in Action names) for where the functionality differs.